# What is this bird called?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I've found this bird.

Does anyone know what is it?

[image]

Comment: Since Asia is pretty big: Where in Asia is this taken?

Comment: You should ask him, I don't know him personally but he looks like a good bloke, he does remind of a Geoffrey though

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is White breasted Kingfisher also called White throated Kingfisher. [*Halcyon smyrnensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-throated_kingfisher).

[image]

### Why this is *Halcyon smyrnensis*?

- [*Halcyon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halcyon_(genus)) kingfishers are mostly large kingfishers with heavy bills.
- According to wikipedia this genus has 11 species, some workers also include genera *Pelargopsis, Syma* and *Todirhamphus*.
- Out of all the 11 species only two are comparable to *H. smyrnensis*; [*Halcyon badia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate-backed_kingfisher) and [*Halcyon coromanda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruddy_kingfisher).
- [*Halcyon badia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate-backed_kingfisher) is an African resident.

Additional information:

> - They are “sit and wait” predators of small ground animals including large insects, rodents, snakes, and frogs, but some will also take fish.
> - The genus *Halcyon* in the current sense consists mainly of species resident in sub-Saharan Africa, with a couple of representatives in southern Asia, one of which, the white-throated kingfisher, occasionally reaches Europe. White-throated and Ruddy kingfishers ([*Halcyon coromanda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruddy_kingfisher)) are at least partially migratory.

Comment: it looks much more nice but has a lot in common

Comment: Added more information to establish as why it is your bird and the similarities are not due to chance. Check [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=white-throated+kingfisher&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBsaa51uLTAhWJso8KHTNWDxEQ_AUIBigB&biw=1366&bih=635) for images from different angles. @griffonvulture